# What Spring strategy should I go with when using query strings to search for an object?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to develop a REST service with Spring 3.1 where users can access information. A resource can easily be accessed by `app/courses/1` to retrieve a course by it's id.

However, I want to make it possible to search. Here is the model:

```
public class Course {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Long points;

    private Long numberOfParticipants;
}
```

For example, what if I wanted to fetch a Course that has `name=foo` and `points=1337`, the corresponding query string would be as follows: `app/courses?name=foo&points=1337`.

I have come up with a temporary solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "courses")
@ResponseBody
public Course getCourse(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
                        @RequestParam(value ="points", required = false) Long points) {

    // TODO
    // Find and return course from the database.
}
```

However, this seems very tedious and messy, my question is therefore: **does Spring have something that simplifies this a bit so I don't have to harvest all the attributes the hard way?**

Comment: You cannot use Annotations as parameters, you have to declare them too.

Comment: Fixed. I can feel I'm falling asleep...

Comment: Go rest, when you wake up, may it be that you will find the solution by your self.

Comment: Yes, I will REST now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/courses")
@ResponseBody
public Course getCourse(Course course) {

}
```

This will map all request parameters to fields of a `Course` command object.